# How to run cron jobs in Node.js Application where cron values are retrievied from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cron

## Running Cron Jobs from Node Application

Hi All,

I have to run cron jobs which I am receiving from MongoDB collection (say 'jobs')
But
these cron timings are mutable by users as per demand,**i.e. users can change the cron values from UI anytime.I am using 'cron' package of npm**
and I am able to schedule the cron as below

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
let cronJobs = []
let currentCronJob 
async function createCronJobs(cronJobs){
    const jobs =  await Jobs.find({},{_id:1,clientId:1,name:1,frequency:1})
    for(let job of jobs){
        if(job.frequency.type == "scheduled"){
            for (let cron_str of job.frequency.schedule){
                currentCronJob = new CronJob(
                    cron_str,
                    function() {
                        console.log("Executed",cron_str,job.name)
                    },
                    null,
                    true,
                    'Asia/Kolkata'
                )
                cronJobs.push(currentCronJob) 
            }
        }
    }
    currentCronJob.start()
}
createCronJobs(cronJobs)
```

In the code I am creating a new connection using Mongoose and iterarting through all docs to check if the frequency.type == "scheduled" If it is scheduled then I am retrieving all cron values and using CronJob method to schedule the cron.

## My Problem

The above code works perfectly fine if the cron timings are not changed, i.e. if it remains same in the jobs collection, However if the cron values are changed over the time then I am not able to execute the job as per the new modified cron.

*Note - I have read about watch package but it says This functionality is only available on a MongoDB Replicaset*

I am also ready for solution or approach other than the given one.

I am asking the question first time on stackoverflow so I am Sorry for any spelling or Grammatical mistakes or if the question is not properly framed.

Comment: according to the [API documentation](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/blob/master/README.md#api), you can and should use `setTime` where it would  _Stops and changes the time for the `CronJob`. Param must be a `CronTime`_

Comment: I am not able to understand, can you add the setTime in the async function which I provided in the code

Comment: sure, i just posted the sample code

Answer (score 1):

bacause the jobs are many,

```
async function createCronJobs(cronJobs){
    const jobs =  await Jobs.find({},{_id:1,clientId:1,name:1,frequency:1})
    for(let job of jobs){
        if(job.frequency.type == "scheduled"){
            for (let cron_str of job.frequency.schedule){
                currentCronJob = new CronJob(
                ....
                )
                currentCronJob.setTime(cron_str) //initiate here
            }
        }       
    }
    //currentCronJob.setTime()
}
createCronJobs(cronJobs)
```

how to trigger the function?

in my opinion, the better way is to add a new param to the function, and set default value null to keep the old cronjob works well. and will only run base on the `userId`

```
async function createCronJobs(cronJobs, userId = null) {
  let jobs = null;
  if (userId) {
    jobs = await Jobs.find(
      { userid: userid },
      { _id: 1, clientId: 1, name: 1, frequency: 1 }
    );
  } else {
    jobs = await Jobs.find({}, { _id: 1, clientId: 1, name: 1, frequency: 1 });
  }

 ....
}
```

so, you can call this function when user updating the cron time.

Comment: Actually I am not able to fetch fresh cron values once the server is started , I think you didn't understand what I said

Comment: @ Tobol Sitanggang My problem is 1)- I want the createCronJob function run again as soon as there is any change found in Jobs Collection because there are chances that new cron timings are added or some cron timings are removed or modified for a particular job.                                                             
 2) But The main thing is How can I detect the change in Jobs collection

Comment: cmiiw, the answer was focus to ` if the cron values are changed over the time then I am not able to execute the job as per the new modified cron`. but yeah, i miss the question about how to trigger the cronjob.

Comment: There is no such thing as UserID in Jobs Collection, I mean the Mongo Schema does not conatain any variable that corresponds to User Id

Comment: yeah, i know if you dont have it, its just an example where you need a `id, name, et` to trigger the function by a parameter to re-run the cronjob for specific job(s) (job(s) that has updated/changed by user), not the whole jobs.

Comment: Oh Sorry Yes there id addedBy which holds the userId But what if the same user has edited the document, in that case the Object Id of addedBy will remain same and this may fail to trigger the function

Comment: i assume you have a function called `updateJob()` to update/create the schedule(s), so you will have to call `createCronJobs()` with the 2nd paramater inside `updateJob()` after the `update process` successfuly

Comment: the reason why you need the second parameter in `createCronJobs()` is because we don't want to change any other users jobs or the other jobs that currently running